# Referencing multiple primary keys in another table

Tags: sql, db2

I am using DB2 to to create some tables.  I have 2 tables that look like this:

```
create table TEST_TABLE1
/* */
(
PRIMARY_COLUMN1 int not null,
PRIMARY_COLUMN2 varchar(50) not null,
primary key (PRIMARY_COLUMN1,PRIMARY_COLUMN2)
);

create table TEST_TABLE2
/* */
(
PRIMARY_COLUMN1 int references TEST_TABLE1(PRIMARY_COLUMN1) not null,
PRIMARY_COLUMN2 varchar(50) references TEST_TABLE1(PRIMARY_COLUMN2) not null,
primary key(PRIMARY_COLUMN1,PRIMARY_COLUMN2)
);
```

When I try to add the tables, I get this error:

```
SQL0573N  A column list specified in the references clause of constraint 
"PRIMARY_COLUMN1..." does not identify a unique constraint of the parent table 
or nickname "DB2INST1.TEST_TABLE1".  SQLSTATE=42890
```

Does anybody know how I can get TEST_TABLE2 to reference TEST_TABLE1?

I have also tried to create TEST_TABLE2 like this and got the same error:

```
create table TEST_TABLE2
/* */
(
PRIMARY_COLUMN1 int references TEST_TABLE1(PRIMARY_COLUMN1) not null,

primary key(PRIMARY_COLUMN1)
);
```

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: What you have here is **one** primary key that happens to contain multiple columns (aka. "composite" or "compound" PK). Since you only have one PK, you only need one FK to reference it. But you need to reference the **whole** PK, not just one of its columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a thumb rule, foreign key has to refer a unique key only.

The logical explanation would be.. Say you have names

```
FIRST LAST
-----------
John Abraham
John Jones
```

When you create a foreign key refence just to refer FIRST column, there may be two values in the parent. Which is obviously ambiguous! Whereas when you create a reference on including both these columns(which is unique), the ambiguity is no more!

The error message you got is stating the same.

```
does not identify a unique constraint of the parent table
```

---

Now..Analysing ur DDL,

```
create table TEST_TABLE1
/* */
(
PRIMARY_COLUMN1 int not null,
PRIMARY_COLUMN2 varchar(50) not null,
primary key (PRIMARY_COLUMN1,PRIMARY_COLUMN2)  <<----- Unique over 2 columns
);
```

You define a PK in Table1 including 2 Columns.

Where-as in second table, you just create a foreign key referring one of those columns! So the error.

```
create table TEST_TABLE2
/* */
(
PRIMARY_COLUMN1 int 
   references TEST_TABLE1(PRIMARY_COLUMN1) not null, <<--------FK refers only one of them?

primary key(PRIMARY_COLUMN1) 
);
```

**And Solution could be:**

```
create table TEST_TABLE2
/* */
(
PRIMARY_COLUMN1 int  not null,
PRIMARY_COLUMN2 varchar(50) not null,
primary key(PRIMARY_COLUMN1,PRIMARY_COLUMN2),
CONSTRAINT my_foreign FOREIGN KEY (PRIMARY_COLUMN1,PRIMARY_COLUMN2)
                    REFERENCES TEST_TABLE1(PRIMARY_COLUMN1,PRIMARY_COLUMN2)
     <<---- Refer both columns..
);
```

Comment: I tried that in the first place and got the same error.  See the edits to my post above for an example.

Comment: Added some explanations

Comment: I can see why my solution does not work.  Is there a way to get it to work?  Can I somehow specify that 2 columns in table 2 are unique in table 1?

Comment: @Added solution, can you try it out please!

Comment: Accepted.  It probably doesn't matter, but in the solution there should be a comma after the primary key line and it should reference TEST_TABLE1 instead of TEST_TABLE2.  I tried editing, but it said it was not enough changes.  It probably doesn't matter, it is clear what you meant.

Comment: Oh Sorry about the typos! Thanks!